# Keyboard shortcut to close a tab in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close a tab in SQL Server Management Studio 2008? like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> in Firefox.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> should work.

Comment: I really wish there was a way to remap this keyboard shortcut, Ctrl+F4 is a stretch!

Comment: @Ben Alt-F,C (File > Close) is easier for the single hand of some. I do it with Caps-C (not a stretch at all) via an AutoHotKey script I use which maps (among other things) Caps-C to Ctrl-F4.

Comment: Can this be remapped?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Yes.  Tools --> Options --> Environment -->Keyboard.  Now search for Window.CloseDocumentWindow.  Change "Use new shortcut in" to "SQL Query Editor".  Now put in your desired shortcut combo and press "Assign".

Comment: Note "Use new shortcut in" must be "SQL Query Editor".  I thought "global" would work but it does not.

Comment: "Global" will work if you remove the conflicting shortcut from `Edit.SelectCurrentWord`. A Global setting will then allow closing other types of tabs (like XML)

Comment: For the lazy, `Ctrl` being in the lower left of my keyboard, I hold it down with the left side of my palm so my middle finger can hit F4. :D

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but you can also change it to Ctrl + w if you want:

**In Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard**

Search for `Edit.SelectCurrentWord` and change it to something else (Like `Ctrl + B`).

Search for `Window.CloseDocumentWindow`. Add CTRL+W as a Global shortcut

*(Credits to https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/2030795)*

Answer (score 5):

@Lance, thanks for you answer. It works, and it makes life easier.

In addition, after doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> you can also press <kbd>N</kbd> if it shows you a 'save changes' confirmation dialog.